# Find all possibilities C#

Tags: c#

I am making a program that will find all the possible combinations of numbers between 0-9 with a 4 digit window. e.i.
0000
0001
0002
0003
/ect

Now I have tried...

```
int[] Possibilities = new int[4];

        int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, r = 0;

        for ( ; ; )
        {
            x++;
            if (x == 9)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }

            if (y ==9)
            {
                y = 0;
                z++;
            }

            if (z == 9)
            {
                z = 0;
                r++;
            }

            Possibilities[0] = x;
            Possibilities[1] = y;
            Possibilities[2] = z;
            Possibilities[3] = r;

                if (Possibilities[0] == 9 && Possibilities[1] == 9 && Possibilities[2] == 9 & Possibilities[3] == 9)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(Possibilities[0]) + Convert.ToString(Possibilities[1]) + Convert.ToString(Possibilities[2]) + Convert.ToString(Possibilities[3]) + " ");
```

And I simply get a program that loops infinity and doesn't do what i want. 
I believe my problem is that I am setting the variable to 0 once the one above is 9 but I am not sure.

Any help would be lovely, thank you.

Comment: This is far less complicated than you have made it.  Possible combinations are 0..n, where n is 10^digits - 1. So... `var combinations = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Pow(10, digits) - 1);` You also forgot an `&` in the last AND in your if statement, so it's `some_bool & Possibilities[3] == 9`.

Comment: Whenever you get `x == 9` you immediately reset it back to zero so that your test to break will never be realized.

Comment: @user3530423: In this case, 4...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you must proceed digit by digit?

Comment: Looking at your source, do i understand correctly that your 4-digit numbers never should contain a '9'? (Note that you reset x, y, and z to '0' whenever it reaches '9' before you output the actual number.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm confused, why can't you just do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("0000"));
}
```

Comment: I did not think that. I make everything complex and this i did the same to :(

Answer (score 2):

All you want are the numbers from 0 to 9999 (not including 9999 according to your source code), with the output fixed to 4 digits with leading zeroes:

```
for (int i=0; i < 9999; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("{0:0000}", i);
```

And just for fun, looking closer at your source code reveals that it skips any '9' digit. I don't know whether this is intentional or a mistake. I think it is a mistake, but anyway... If it is intentional, the following code snippet would achieve skipping any number containing a '9':

```
for (int i=0; i < 9999; ++i)
{
    string s = i.ToString("0000");
    if (!s.Contains("9"))
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

(There are a few other ways to do it, for example with Linq, but let's keep it simple...)